# Groups without "almost equivariant" coarse embeddings

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, coarse-geometry

Let $X$ be a set. We say that $\psi:X\times X\to[0,\infty)$ is a CND (conditionally negative definite) kernel if there is a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and a map $f:X\to\mathcal{H}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\psi(x,y)=\|f(x)-f(y)\|^2,\quad\forall x,y\in X.
\end{align*}

Let us consider the following property for a countable group $\Gamma$.

**(P)** There is a CND kernel $\psi:\Gamma\times\Gamma\to[0,\infty)$ and a constant $C>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\psi(sx,sy)\leq\psi(x,y)+C,\quad\forall s,x,y\in\Gamma,
\end{align*}
and $\psi(x,1)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

This can be thought of as an "almost equivariant" coarse embedding into a Hilbert space.

**Question:** Besides the class of groups that are not coarsely embeddable, are there groups that do not satisfy **(P)**?

The motivation behind this question comes from the fact that this property characterises groups admitting a proper uniformly Lipschitz affine action on a subspace of an $L^1$ space; see [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.12949).

[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.12949) I. Vergara. *Almost invariant CND kernels and proper uniformly Lipschitz actions on subspaces of $L^1$.* [arXiv:2109.12949](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.12949)

Comment: Just for context, a group for which this exists with $C=0$ is called a group with the Haagerup property. Do you know an example of a non-Haagerup group with such a kernel?

Comment: @YCor: OP's paper provides such examples, e.g. all residually finite hyperbolic groups satisfying property (T) also satisfy (P).